# How could it be determined whether an image is an image of an image or of a real 3d object?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

E.g. can the following two images be distinguished: I take my camera and take a picture of my car; and then I take the picture, print it out and photograph the picture again (assuming that the camera, printer and lighting conditions are perfect both times)? After shuffling both pictures at random, how could I tell which picture is which - using Python?

Comment: If the picture of the picture is taken under ideal circumstances, it will be distinguishable from the first picture. In real life you might be able to pick up on artefacts produced by the printer, by not-ideal illumination of the printed page, by geometric distortions, etc. This is definitely not trivial, and way out of scope for a question on Stack Overflow. Probably more suited for a PhD thesis, unless it's already been done: start with a literature search!

Comment: Thank you. Is there a solution for videos? If someone records a video and walks around the 3d object, then a person can recognize that it is a 3d object and not a picture of a 3d object. Could this be recognized programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

Not easily done, when the intent is to deceive the viewer, or much of the movie visual effects industry would not exist. Even in 1968 an in-camera effect genius like Stanley Kubrick could do [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wstIBq2H0z8&t=31s) with nothing more than a wall-size print and the right illumination.